# Best approach to pass data back to previous page when go back in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, navigation

What would be the best approach to pass data back to the previous page when I click the back button in Windows Phone.
What I want to do is, when the user goes back to the main page from one of my child pages, if I saved something in the child page, the main page should refresh de data.
When I go forward is simple, I simply use the QueryStringm, but I don't know how to do when I go back.
I tried this:

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_BackKeyPress(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    NavigationContext.QueryString.Add("test", "test");
}
```

and then, in the main page I tried to do this:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NavigationMode == System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationMode.Back)
    {
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("test"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(NavigationContext.QueryString["test"]);
        }
    }
}
```

I did this just for testing purposes, but I had no luck, I've searched the internet for an answer but I didn't find any satisfying one.
I thought about putting in the App.xaml.cs a dictionary called Pending, where I would hold data that should be handled at certain points, and then, if I went back to the main page and I had the data in this dictionary I would refresh the ui.
Would it be a good idea??

Thank you all!

Comment: What didn't work in the first case? What happens? The app doesn't navigate back? Or the NavigationContext.QueryString doesn't containt "TEST" key?

Comment: The QueryString doesn't contain the test key...

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend is if you are following the MVVM architecture, set a property in the view model from child page and access it on the parent page. I hope it helps you

Comment: I'm using MVVM. But I would need to keep the child's viewmodel instantiated, How would I access the child's page view model. And I would have to handle if the child page isn't this one...

Comment: In the app settings you can create an instance of viewmodel and use it throughout your code in all your views. In this way you will have to maintain only one viewmodel for all your views. Hence same properties will become accessible on both parent and child pages. I hope this helps but let me know if you have any further doubt.